# Pivot MySQL - How to move data from one table to a new one

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Let's say I have an old_table with 74 columns resumed here:

```
ID  NICKNAME    FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
7   Nick1       Name1       Lastname1
8   Nick2       Name2       Lastname2
```

And I need to have this data moved and pivoted to an new_table in MySQL for import the users data to Wordpress.

```
UMETA_ID    USER_ID     META_KEY    META_VALUE
1           7           NICKNAME    Nick1
2           7           FIRST_NAME  Name1
3           7           LAST_NAME   Lastname1
4           8           NICKNAME    Nick2
5           8           FIRST_NAME  Name2
6           8           LAST_NAME   Lastname2
```

How can I achieve this in MySQL? Thanks in advance and all the best for whom that can help a fish out of his water.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I modelled the old_table column names and sequences to match the sequence of the rows at the new_table using Navicat. That part was fine but I spent almost one day. But my knowledge of MySQL commands to proceed with this migration is zero. I know this is not difficult. I found one quiz here that the dude was doing exactly the inverse. I tried the commands that He did, but the repetition of the ID values of old_table in several rows of the new_table is not working.

Comment: Thanks Alex for ur help. And at the Question itself too. I was trying to delete for correction, than... saw corrected. /o\

It was fine to insert the rows and data, helps a lot. BUT, I noticed that the "-" in column names gave a huge bug to move (?). Than I changed to "_" and success!

Answer (score 1):

You can start from:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57543/2

```
INSERT INTO new (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
SELECT old.id, 'NICKNAME', old.nickname FROM old
UNION
SELECT old.id, 'FIRST_NAME', old.first_name FROM old
UNION
SELECT old.id, 'LAST_NAME', old.last_name FROM old
```